# Issues when switching an Azure SQL connection from SQL Server authentication to AAD-based authentication

Tags: power-automate, powerapps, powerapps-canvas

Facing a few unexpected issues when switching in a canvas PowerApp an Azure SQL connection from SQL Server authentication to AAD authentication.

- The new AAD-based authentication works in design mode but not in play
  mode. No error displayed. Not sure how to investigate this failure.
- While SQL Server authentication based connections allow using env variables to
  specify things such as server name and database name, AAD-based
  authentication connections do not and this creates an important
  challenge when having to move an application to a new env. How are applications with such connections supposed to be imported
  in a new environment?

Creating a new app from scratch that uses the AAD-based connection to Azure SQL everything works as expected both in design and play but we are facing a challenge in successfully switching the connection for an existing app.